# Realtek driver rtl8723bu on Chuwi Herobook Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek

following the guide here 
[Wifi is Not Working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with RTL8723BU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056910/wifi-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-with-rtl8723bu)

I made wifi work

BUT problems:

still remains double wifi despite of adding # in EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE line in Makefile

but most important everytime i logout or change desktop enviroment wifi stop to work,i have to reboot, how can is solve? Thanks!!!

Comment: Mmm yes Sorry, it's Ubuntu mate 18.04

Comment: As per the link you provided, did you  revert to the in-tree driver with _sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rtl8xxxu.conf_ ?

Comment: Until now, it worked!!! Thanks!

Comment: Let's if it last.. another problem: bluetooth. How can i make it work? There's only symbol but no way to connect to anything. Sorry for being so noob

Comment: Another problem? Ask another question? It's one issue per question here at AskUbuntu.com just like all other StackExchange.com websites, because the purpose of these Q&A sites is to build an infobase for that category of issues; therefore, one issue per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you revert to the in-tree driver with

`sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rtl8xxxu.conf`

which reverts to the driver [officially accepted in the kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208643/7264).