# Connection Failed: Activation of Network Connection...What should I do?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I'm very new to Ubuntu as I just came from Windows. I want to say that Ubuntu with Gnome is much faster, smoother and the UI is amazing!

However, I cannot seem to consistently connect to my own Wi-Fi despite being 2m away from it. I even placed my laptop right next to the antennas yet I still get an error message saying,

> Connection Failed: 
>   Activation of Network Connection Failed

I don't think it's a physical issue as all of my devices can connect to it (Kindle Fire, Various smartphones...)

I have tried installing the new kernels for Realtek cards but still gives me the same error.

Could someone give me advice?

Thanks!

---

Edit 1: The Output of the 'lshw'

```
 description: Notebook
    product: Hero Book (N/A)
    vendor: CHUWI INNOVATION LIMITED
    version: Type1 - TBD by OEM
    serial: HeroBookR64G19073703
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=N/A sku=N/A uuid=F75E53A5-0958-AC47-AFBA-AE4776CF52E1
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: N/A
       vendor: N/A
       physical id: 0
       version: Type2 - Board Version
       serial: HeroBookR64G19073703
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: INSYDE Corp.
          physical id: 0
          version: E115C.CHUWI.B011
          date: 01/19/2019
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 3008KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb zipboot biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Atom(TM) x5-E8000  CPU @ 1.04GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Atom(TM) x5-E8000  CPU @ 1.04GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: CHV
          size: 902MHz
          capacity: 2GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 83MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat md_clear cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 5
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 24KiB
          capacity: 24KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
          configuration: level=1
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 23
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
             vendor: 0000
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 8 bits
             clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
             vendor: 0000
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 8 bits
             clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 35
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=iosf_mbi_pci
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 35
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:120 memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:1000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0b.0
             version: 35
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:118 memory:91218000-91218fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 35
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:115 memory:91200000-9120ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.3.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.03
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=7 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Video
                   product: USB 2.0 Camera
                   vendor: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: USB hub
                   product: USB 2.0 Hub
                   vendor: Terminus Technology Inc.
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@1:4
                   version: 1.11
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: Generic USB device
                      product: USB2.0-CRW
                      vendor: Generic
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: usb@1:4.2
                      version: 39.60
                      serial: 20100201396000000
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=rtsx_usb maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
                   vendor: Realtek
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@1:5
                   version: 2.00
                   serial: 00e04c000001
                   capabilities: usb-2.10 bluetooth
                   configuration: driver=rtl8xxxu maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.3.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.03
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic:1
             description: Encryption controller
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 35
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_txe latency=0
             resources: irq:119 memory:91100000-911fffff memory:91000000-910fffff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 35
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:121 memory:91210000-91213fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 35
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 35
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:91219000-9121901f ioport:1040(size=32)
  *-battery
       description: Lithium Ion Battery
       product: SR Real Battery
       vendor: Intel SR 1
       physical id: 1
       version: Date
       serial: 123456789
       slot: I2C2
       configuration: voltage=3.8V
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: OEM Define 1
       product: OEM Define 5
       vendor: OEM Define 2
       physical id: 2
       version: OEM Define 6
       serial: OEM Define 3
       capacity: 75mWh
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: wlxac5d5c9422c5
       serial: ac:5d:5c:94:22:c5
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=5.3.0-46-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.149 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

---

Edit 2: Added 'lsusb' output

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:6321 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

Edit 3: Attempted to Install 'rtl8723bu' via https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu/blob/master/README.md

**Results:** Installed rtl8723bu driver for RealTek with 0bda:b720, while blacklisting rtl8xxu. Despite this, I still get a weak signal, PC cannot recognize the Wifi signal from time to time despite being 10 centimeters away from it. Thinking of buying a USB adapter to resolve this, but installing new drivers for TP-Link might be a hassle for now.

**What keeps me going:** I really love Ubuntu, I fell in love with the smoothness, the UI, the applications...don't want to give up yet! I really do not want to return to Windows 10 for it feels clunky.

Comment: Perhaps start [with lshw](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw) as an output of the hardware, and we can go from there.

Comment: Edit your question with this as an output.

Comment: Thanks for that! @DankyNanky

Comment: Are you using a USB device? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` device.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done! Here it is!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wifi is Not Working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with RTL8723BU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056910/wifi-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-with-rtl8723bu)

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for the link! I have done the solutions and my Wi-Fi seems to be working for now, but with a very weak signal despite placing it right next to my wireless router... With Windows 10, I had no problems being in the living room, but now I can't seem to be 1m away from my Wi-Fi anymore...